# Is it possible to pass an attribute argument from a derived class to its base class?

Tags: c#, attributes, radix, derived-class

Is it possible to pass an attribute argument from a derived class to its base class?

Essentially, I'm trying set a property's attribute's argument from the derived class.

- How it could be done in C++

  ```
  public class HasHistory<T, string name> {
      public HasHistory() {
          History=new History<T>();
      }

      // here's my attribute
      [BsonElement(name)]
      public History<T> History {
          get;
          protected set;
      }
  }
  ```

  However, **non-type template arguments** is legal in C++, but **illegal in C#**.
- What an unexpected workaround in C#

  I realize I could make the property virtual, and add the attribute in the derived class. But then I'd be calling a virtual function in the constructor, and while that might work, it's poor practice.

  I do want to make that call because I want the base class constructor to initialize the member; that's in fact the whole point of the base class.

  ```
  public class HasHistory<T> {
      public HasHistory() {
          // this will be called before Derived is constructed
          // and so the vtbl will point to the property method
          // defined in this class.
          // We could probably get away with this, but it smells.
          History=new History<T>();
      }

      // here's my property, without an Attribute
      public virtual History<T> History {
          protected set;
          get;
      }
  }

  public class Derived: HasHistory<SomeType> {
      // crap! I made this virtual and repeated the declaration
      // just so I could add an attribute!
      [BsonElement("SomeTypeHistory")]
      public virtual HasHistory<SomeType> History {
          protected set;
          get;
      }
  }
  ```

  So I suppose I could not put the attribute in the base, and instead put it on a derived class property that uses/is implemented in terms of a protected base class property, but that's cumbersome enough that it obviates any convenience gained by using the base class.

So there's a good way to do this, right? Right?

How do I redefine an attribute on a property of derived class which inherits form the base **WITHOUT overriding the property** in the derived class?

Comment: Not sure what you're doing with the `<T, string name>` portion in the generic.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair It's invalid, but he's trying to illustrate he wants a C# mechanism like C++'s template arguments.

Comment: Have you tried to apply the attribute in base class? As far as I know it does not possible to pass variable into attribute, since attribute is being processed during compile time and not run time.

Comment: The above doesn't make much sense. Type variables are really more akin to placeholders that are replaced on demand with the actual type being requested (when an instance of the generic class is instantiated). If you were to use `string`, for example, then your attribute would be showing `[BsonElement(string)]`, which is not valid for compilation.

Comment: What are you hoping to accomplish with this attribute, maybe there's another way to approach the problem?

Comment: "calling a virtual function in the constructor" Not strictly correct. You are setting a virtual property, and in your case it is simple, and will do no harm.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** Darn, you already considered this.  I should have updated before posting :)

Unfortunately what you want to do is well outside scope for C#'s attribute mechanism.  Generics are different to templates, so this kind of workaround is about as good as it gets.

Mostly you're going to be defining an attribute at the top level anyway, so generally this isn't a problem.  When it *is* a problem - as apparently in your case - then you have to use the ugly workarounds.

**Original answer below...**

---

If I understand the example correctly, you're wanting to apply an attribute to a class member based on some value declared in/by the derived type.  Since C# doesn't support non-type parameters for Generics you need another way to do this.

One thing you might be able to do is override the property within the descendant class like this:

```
public class HasHistory<T>
{
    public HasHistory() 
    {
        History = new History<T>();
    }

    public virtual History<T> History { get; protected set; }
}

public class MyHistory<T> : HasHistory<T>
{
    public MyHistory()
        : base()
    {}

    [BSONElement("some name")]
    public override History<T> History 
    { 
        get
        {
            return base.History;
        }
        protected set
        {
            base.History = value;
        }
    }
}
```

The code that uses the `BsonElement` attribute will be working with the *actual* type of the derived `HasHistory<T>` instance, so it will be looking at the attributes defined at the end of the `virtual` chain.  Given the code above, if I create a `MyHistory<T>` instance and pass it to the BSON serializer it will find the attribute attached to the `History` property within the `MyHistory<T>` class.

You can however define an attribute at the base level and override it in the derived classes where necessary.  Not sure if this is going to be useful in your case.

It's more work, especially since you have to do this in each derived class, but I think this is as close as you're going to get to the C++ Template style in this case.  I'd be happy to be proved wrong however :)

Comment: The problem here is that you now have a virtual method call in the base constructor.  I haven't found a solution to this.

Comment: Yeah, I spotted that after I posted the original answer and found you'd updated the question.  Basically it comes down to this being outside the capabilities of the language at the moment.

Comment: It would be nice if there were a way to 'override' attributes... whatever that would mean.

Comment: Attributes are decorations of *types* not *instances*.  An attribute can't even find out what it is decorating unless you tell it explicitly as a parameter to a method call.  If you want instance-specific differences you need a *property*.

Comment: And just to prove that C# is more flexible than we generally give it credit for, and far more dangerous under the hood.... If you don't care about `mono` compatibility, and don't mind having a lot of code to support it, you might be able to get a step closer to what you're after by using `TypeDescriptor` to manipulate the type's metadata at run-time.  See for instance: http://geekswithblogs.net/abhijeetp/archive/2009/01/10/dynamic-attributes-in-c.aspx

Comment: sure, so how does one avoid a virtual method call?  I was just idly floating an undefined idea to avoid this particular problem.

Comment: `so how does one avoid a virtual method call?` Move the property into the parent class?  Or just use the virtual method call.  It's frowned on, but you *can* do it.

Comment: One can, but it's not a good idea.  The point is I would like the property to be decorated with different attributes, depending upon extra requirements in the derived class.  I've redesigned it to avoid the problem, so I guess that's the solution- use a different design. ;)